# A transparent image I'm linking to isn't transparent when being displayed

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

So the title says it all, I've tried it with a few different definitely transparent images, they all just show the white and gray background that transparent images have.

I've tried adding `style="transparent"` to the image tag but it doesn't do anything. It's a React app if that has an affect. It's being displayed in a regular html table.

Edit, my code:

```
<img src="https://w0.pngwave.com/png/1013/469/computer-icons-check-mark-symbol-ok-png-clip-art-thumbnail.png"  styles="transparent" width="50px" height="50px"/>;
```

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the image you are using is not transparent, the image creator added some texture on it to make it look like it is transparent.
Check this image instead

```
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Tick_Mark_Dark-512.png">
```

Comment: Why would a person do that?